# Node serialport communication with hardware with CRC16

Tags: node.js, crc16, node-serialport

Hello We are working on node application to control hardware..

Hardware is bill recycle.

The communication with serial port is done via Hex code ..

But we are not sure how to calculate CRC16 and then send data via serial port.

## Below is code

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
var CRC16 = require('crc16');
const path = "/dev/ttyS0";
var port = new SerialPort(path,
  {
    autoOpen: false,
    Timeout:1000,
    EncryptionStatus: 0,
    BaudRate:9600,
    RetryLevel : 3 ,
    SSPAddress : 0,
    PortNumber : 0,
    CommandDataLength : 1,

   }, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Error: ', err.message);
  }
});

port.open(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Error opening port: ', err.message);
      }} );
 port.on("open", function (err) {
   if(err) console.log(err);
   port.on('data', function (data) {
     console.log('Data: on data : ', data);
     console.log("from data ", data.toString('hex'));

     let json = JSON.stringify(data);
     console.log(json);
   });
      write_data = Buffer.from('7F80010A3F82','hex');
    port.write(Buffer.from('7F8001051D82','hex'), function(err) {        console.log('message written')});
  });

 port.on('close', function() { console.log(' DISCONNECTED ') });
 port.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Error: ', err.message);
    })
```

Below are instructions 
[Transport Layer Datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQzEi.png)

here is online doc : https://sensis.ru/files/bv50-ssp-manual.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Did you Try as Follows :

```
CRC16(stringOrBuffer, [optional] encoding)
```

**Example:**

```
CRC16('7F8001051D82', 'hex')
```

Then in your `port.write()` you can use the output of `CRC16()`.

**Example:**

```
data_to_send = CRC16('7F8001051D82', 'hex')
port.write(data_to_send)
```

[NPM Repository link of CRC16](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crc16)

Comment: Nope. That code implements CRC-16/XMODEM. The one specified in the documentation is a CRC-16/CMS, which uses both a different polynomial and a different initial value. There are [many, many CRC-16's](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm).

Comment: i have used `crc-16/MODBUS` and `crc-16/KERMIT` before, as i saw the OP used a crc-16 package so i suggested to use it's default method to see the results if it works first, i did implement it using `C#` with different polynomials but cannot find those now. Well, thanks for your clarification though :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation in C of the [CRC-16/CMS](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm#crc.cat.crc-16-cms) specified in the documentation:

```
unsigned crc16cms(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0xffff;
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= (unsigned)(*data++) << 8;
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 0x8000 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x8005 : crc << 1;
    }
    crc &= 0xffff;
    return crc;
}
```

When called with `mem == NULL` it returns the initial CRC. The routine can be called sequentially with a series of input buffers to calculate the CRC of their concatenation, starting with `crc` equal to the initial CRC and feeding each resulting CRC as the next input `crc`.